# Shuffling a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a class that is essentially a pseudo-library. The driver creates the library NoviceLibrary that can do different things, like add books to the library (nodes to the linked list ListNode), remove books, and such and such.

The shuffleBooks() is the very last function I have to write. Everything else works and can add/remove books. This function needs to put the nodes in the linked list in random order. I cannot use a tail pointer, which I've seen in other algorithms. I can't use arrays. What I thought I had written was that there are pointers p1 and p2 that swap nodes in the list. The program stalls and doesn't give me useful information in the log.

```
void shuffleBooks (int bookCount)
{
      int r1 = rand() % bookCount;
      int r2 = rand() % bookCount;

      ListNode *p1 = head;
      ListNode *p2 = head;

      // Here I am trying to get the swap to happen 4 times the bookCount
      for (int i = 0; i < bookCount*4; i++)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++)
            p1 = p1->next;

         for (int i = 0; i < r2; i++)
            p2 = p2->next;

         swap(p1->bookVal, p2->bookVal);
      }
}
```

Comment: Code goes in the question please (otherwise the question becomes useless when the link goes dead)

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: _"I am not sure where I'm going wrong."_ - That's OK, we're not sure what you're asking so we're even.

Comment: Let me rephrase and try to make it clear. Sorry about that!

Comment: `p1`, `p2`, `r1` and `r2` should be inside the `for` loop and `swap` is just swapping the values in `p1` and `p2`, not the contents of the objects they point to.

Comment: Should it be swap(p1->bookVal, p2->bookVal) instead?

Comment: Holy cow. I did as you said and stuck them inside the loop and re-wrote that swap. It did it. It actually did it. I'd been staring at that for so long. THANK YOU.

Comment: Also, for cleanliness you should probably use a different variable name for the index for your outer loop if you are going to use `i` for the two inner loops.

Comment: To back up a second, simple linked lists are very rarely the right answer to any problem.  While "it is cheap to delete and add items in the middle", getting to the middle is so slow that getting to it + deleting it is way slower than getting to it + deleting it on a `std::vector` (or other contiguous storage).  About the only thing they grant over a contiguous buffer based solution (or chain of large contiguous buffers for extremely large data sets) is pointer-to-element (or reference/iterator-to-element) stability, and (if not `std::list`) O(1) large splice.

Answer (score 0):

Very close, but is swapping the pointers shuffling the list? For shuffling, don't we need to link the nodes differently? We have to be careful that we don't disconnect the list.

Instead of swapping the pointers, how about swapping their successors? From randomness perspective, that is equally good. And this makes re-linking easy.

Following is a schematic for a one iteration of the swap-shuffle.

```
list: A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> G -> H
r1: 2 (say)
r2: 4 (say)
p1: C
p2: F

swap p1->next (D) and p2->next (G)

  // save pointers
  p1next = p1->next;         // D
  p1nextnext = p1next->next; // E
  p2next = p2->next;         // G
  p2nextnext = p2next->next; // H

  // relink
  p1->next = p2next;         // C -> G
  p2next->next = p1nextnext; // G -> E
  p2->next = p1next;         // F -> D
  p1next->next = p2nextnext; // D -> H

list: A -> B -> C -> G -> E -> F -> D -> H

Real code need to be careful not to dereference a null pointer.
```

We can do the above step `k` times to obtain a good shuffle. What's a good value of `k`? I am not sure, perhaps square root of list length.

Comment: First, thanks for answering. I appreciate the kindness. Second, I'm trying to follow along. What does r1: 2 (say) and r2:4 mean? And look back on my code, I suppose it would be more accurate to say it is not actually shuffling nodes, but instead randomly swapping the pointer->bookVal information between nodes?

Comment: You are welcome, I found the problem interesting. Hope the answer helps little bit. Responses: (1) For my example, I assumed r1 and r2 values, based on rand(), are 2 and 4 respectively. (2) At the time of my answering, the question had the code `swap(p1, p2);`. Your current code of swapping the pointed to elements, i.e. `swap(p1->bookVal, p2->bookVal);` Initially, I was concerned about swapping arbitrary size elements. However, assuming efficient element swap implementation, on second thought, I think swapping the elements is better approach than pointer relinking.